# DNP Driver on ScadaLTS

Tags: scadalts

I am using the DNP driver of ScadaLTS, but enabling the datasource, I am having 100% peak of cpu in java. Has anyone ever had anything like it and if so, have you solved it?

Comment: For now we do not use this protocol. Please tell us how can we replicate this using some emulator.